# Bootstrap - Resize inner tag inside container-fluid class issue

Tags: html, css, resize, responsive

i'm creating Box container using Bootstrap framework. only container width is getting resize. I want container as well as inner tags inside should get resize from all 4 sides when we resize browser window

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <style>
    body {
  background-color: #f4f0ec; }

.padding-zero {
  padding: 0px; }

.square-border {
  border: #000 solid 3.5px; }

ul.no-left-border-style {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-right: #000 solid 3.5px; }
  ul.no-left-border-style li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 30px 31px 31px 31px;
    border-bottom: #000 solid 3.5px; }
  ul.no-left-border-style li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none; }

ul.no-right-border-style {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-left: #000 solid 3.5px; }
  ul.no-right-border-style li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 30px 31px 31px 31px;
    border-bottom: #000 solid 3.5px; }
  ul.no-right-border-style li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none; }

.fa {
  font-size: 30px !important;
  color: #2a2b2a; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">Eveniet, voluptatem.</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-12 padding-zero square-border">
          <div class="pull-left">
            <ul class="no-left-border-style">
              <li><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="clear-fix"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">Cupiditate, dolore.</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 padding-zero square-border">
          <div class="pull-right">
            <ul class="no-right-border-style">
              <li><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="clear-fix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hellow you Mean, Something like This?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
    body {
  background-color: #f4f0ec; }

.padding-zero {
  padding: 0px; }

.square-border {
  border: #000 solid 3.5px; }

ul.no-left-border-style {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-right: #000 solid 3.5px; }
  ul.no-left-border-style li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 30px 31px 31px 31px;
    border-bottom: #000 solid 3.5px; }
  ul.no-left-border-style li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none; }

ul.no-right-border-style {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-left: #000 solid 3.5px; }
  ul.no-right-border-style li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 30px 31px 31px 31px;
    border-bottom: #000 solid 3.5px; }
  ul.no-right-border-style li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none; }

.fa {
  font-size: 30px !important;
  color: #2a2b2a; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">Eveniet, voluptatem.</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-12 padding-zero square-border">
          <div class="pull-left col-xs-12">
            <ul class="no-left-border-style">
              <li><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="clear-fix"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">Cupiditate, dolore.</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 padding-zero square-border">
          <div class="pull-right">
            <ul class="no-right-border-style">
              <li><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="clear-fix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please check with below reference link and try to resize the browser. i'm trying to do exactly same
http://publicis.sapient.com/en-us.html